# Do mules or hinnies exist?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

In *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* we see numerous types of creatures: ponies (obviously), zebras, buffalo, sheep, donkeys, dragons, as well as numerous woodland and farm creatures such as butterflies, bears, chickens, and ducks.

However, we have yet to see any mules. Do mules/hinnies exist in the MLP universe? If so, are they treated as a metaphor in any way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We actually have seen mules, and they've been mentioned several times besides.  In "Applebuck Season", after Twilight says that Applejack is as stubborn as a mule, she then apologizes to [a mule](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Wildlife#Mule) that suddenly appears standing next to her; a similar exchange occurs in the beginning of "Hurricane Fluttershy" after Rainbow Dash says "Be cool or be a mule."

[image: "No offense"]

The diamond dogs in "A Dog and Pony Show" also call Rarity a mule, which she takes offense to, as she believes mules are ugly.  A joke about a donkey and a mule is partially heard in "Putting Your Hoof Down".  Finally (and most recently), there's [Mulia Mild](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Mulia_Mild):

[image: Mulia Mild]

Answer (score 6):

As of "Rarity Takes Manehattan", hinnies have been *mentioned* too -- in the title of the stage musical, *Hinny Of The Hills*.

Answer (score 1):

All of the "mules" in MLP are actually donkeys. Mules inherit some horse-like traits from their mother, the mare, and their father, the jack. Most notably mules inherit the long ears of the donkey and have the tail of a horse. If you look at the tails of all of the "mules" you will see that it is a donkey-like tail not a horse-like tail. So, to answer your question, yes, sort of: they say there are(examples are Mulia Mild, Cranky Doodle Ryan(comics), and a few other unnamed mules) ,but they actually aren't mules.